# vertical line on content based height inside flex

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a reusable horizontal component, it works fine with horizontal cases, but when trying on vertical I am not getting the expected result.

**style.css**

```
.horizontal-rule {
  height: 1px;
  background: grey;
  border: none;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.vertical {
  width: 1px;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  height: 100%;
}
```

even though I am adding the **.vertical** class it's not reflecting, so I need to especially pass these inline styles to make working

```
 style={{ height: "48px", border: "solid 1px" }}
```

How can I avoid this inline style and make it a reusable one which will work for vertical cases with height automatically between the content?

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-chandrasekhar-e9ezn)

Comment: I misunderstood your question. Does using min-height for the divider instead of height solve your problem? height:100% is tricky specifically when the container does not have a defined height. If you set a height on its parent you would see it works.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have to set the `height` of parents tag(`.inner-div`) of the `.vertical`.

After that, `height: 100%` in `.vertical` will work as you've intended.

```
.inner-div { height: 48px; }
```

Comment: I don't want to give any height, I have read that inside a flex whatever the content height is it should work